# Array.push - "Maximum call stack size exceeded" из за простого Math.random(). Почему?

Tags: javascript

Есть код, генерирующий массив из 10`000 случайных целых чисел от 0 до 1`000`000`000

```js
let numbers = (() => {
    let arr = [], n = 10000;

    function generate(i) {
        arr.push((Math.random() * 1000000000 | 0));

        if (i < n) {
            generate(++i);
        }
    }

    generate(1);

    return arr;
})();

console.log(numbers);
```

Хочу, чтобы в момент генерации случайного числа к каждому из них прибавлялось еще одно случайное число от 0 до 1, сгенерированное при помощи `Math.random()`, чтобы в итоге получилось число с плавающей точкой

```js
let numbers = (() => {
    let arr = [], n = 10000;

    function generate(i) {
        arr.push((Math.random() * 1000000000 | 0) + Math.random()); // изменения здесь

        if (i < n) {
            generate(++i);
        }
    }

    generate(1);

    return arr;
})();

console.log(numbers);
```

Но на выходе получаю "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Array.push".

**Вопрос**: почему так?

Интересно, что если прибавить вместо `Math.random` любое другое число от 0 до 1 (статичное), то проблема не возникает.

---

**Заметил**, что ".stack size exceeded at *Array.push*" иногда с неопределенной периодичностью сменяется на ".stack size exceeded at *Math.random*".

Comment: стек javascript-a маленький а у тебя 10000  рекурсии там .

Comment: @Избытоксусликов без `Math.random()` все прекрасно работает даже для большего чем 10000 количества генерируемых чисел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.random` здесь ни при чем. При глубине вложенных вызовов 10000, любая лишняя локальная переменная имеет эффект в 10000 раз больше своего размера. Движок завел временную переменную под второй операнд - и все.

(То есть `Math.random` может быть "при чем" - как дополнительный вызов функции, требующий сохранения еще одного stackframe-а.)

С локальной переменной в рекурсивной функции:

```js
let numbers = (() => {
  let arr = [],
    n = 10000;
  //let b = 1;

  function generate(i) {
    let a = 2; //Math.random();// * 1000000000 | 0;
    let b = 1; //Math.random();
    arr.push(a + b); // изменения здесь

    if (i < n) {
        generate(++i);
    }
  }

  generate(1);

  return arr;
})();

console.log(numbers.length, numbers);
```

Без локальной переменной в рекурсивной функции:

```js
let numbers = (() => {
  let arr = [],
    n = 10000;
  let b = 1;

  function generate(i) {
    let a = 2; //Math.random();// * 1000000000 | 0;
    //let b = 1; //Math.random();
    arr.push(a + b); // изменения здесь

    if (i < n) {
        generate(++i);
    }
  }

  generate(1);

  return arr;
})();

console.log(numbers.length, numbers);
```

В разных браузерах - предел разный. Оба примерa у меня работают без ошибок в IE, Edge, Firefox. Чтобы продемонстрировать различное поведение, значение `n` в этих браузерах надо увеличить.

Comment: Очень интересно. Совсем не подумал об этом. Спасибо!